# Firebug not showing JS errors anymore

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I don't know what I did wrong, but Firebug no longer shows JS errors in 'Errors' pane on 'Console'.

For instance, if my page has a form with a 'onsubmit=checkData()', if the function checkData() has JS errors, firebug doesn't show it and the form simply is submitted anyway.

How can I make Firebug show errors again? It always worked well until yesterday.

I already tried to click on the 'Pause' button with no success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure that "All" is selected in the row of choices on the "Console" tab.

Comment: Selecting 'All' or 'Erros' has the same result, no JS errors is show.

Comment: wrap the body of `checkData` in a `try/catch`. In your `catch(e)`, `console.log(e);` and `return false`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use an event handler use a try catch block as errors tend not to be logged in that situation.